# How to align buttons at the right bottom of panel

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styles

I have this CSS code:

```
  .mainBody {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    width: 895px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 8rem;
    top: 40px;
    height: 310px;
   }

 .label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
   }

  .dropdown {
    padding-left: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   }

   .paragraph {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 800px;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
     padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .expandedLink {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 1rem 10rem;
    }

    .previousButton {
      position: relative;
      top: 77px;
      float: right;
    }

    .nextButton {
      position: relative;
      top: 77px;
      float: right;
    }

HTML:

   <div className="mainBody">
    <div className="label"></div>
    <div className="dropdown"></div>
    <div className="paragraph"></div>
    <div className="expandedLink"></div>
    <div className="nextButton"></div>
    <div className="previousButton"></div>
   <div>
```

I want to align the nextButton and previousButton at the bottom right of the mainBody. The problem is that I cannot use margin-top because I am using an expanded component and the content inside mainBody does not have a stable size. Any ideas?

Comment: what was wrong in current code share which type of output you need? and current output

Comment: add `display:flex; justify-content:flex-end;` to `.mainBody`

Comment: remove `positions` and `top` from buttons

Comment: @raviramani Hi. This works perfectly. The thing is that between .mainBody and buttons I have some other elements which I want also to be stable. How can I do this when expanding and when not expanding? I edited my code up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this lines to .mainBody

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly. The thing is that between .mainBody and buttons I have some other elements which I want also to be stable. How can I do this when expanding and when not expanding? I edited my code up.

Comment: if you can give me the image then I can get idea what you want then I can create pen to help you but now  I can not understand your code completely

Comment: sometime need to use proper HTML Structure is important  to design best so if you can give me image then I can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to postion the **.previousButton** and **.nextButton** as absolute.Since the **.mainBody** is relative, an element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

```
    .previousButton {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  float: right;
}

.nextButton {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the buttonclasses to absolute, and add `bottom: 0; right: 0;`. And maybe right for the other button a little bit higher.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something by using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with the following HTML:

```
<div className="mainBody">
    <div className="mainBodyContent">
        Main Body Content
    </div>
    <div className="buttonsContainer">
        <div className="nextButton">Next</div>
        <div className="previousButton">Prev</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this modified CSS:

```
.mainBody {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  width: 895px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 40px;
  min-height: 310px;
}

.mainBodyContent {
  padding-bottom: 8rem; 
}

.buttonsContainer {
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.previousButton {
  padding: 10px;
}

.nextButton {
  padding: 10px;

}
```

I have the example in the following JSFiddle for you to test:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ey35uwt/

---

### Notes

1. I modified the `height`property you had in `.mainBody` to
   `min-height`, because as I understood your question, the body's
   height is variable, and otherwise, the component wouldn't grow with
   the content, but if that's not the intention, you can change it back
   easily.
2. With the same intention, I had the `padding`moved to the content of
   your component.
3. I added some padding to the buttons to avoid them being right on the line and touching each other, but you may want to change that.
4. I grouped the buttons together in a single `.buttonsContainer` div to do the aligning of the buttons in a single place, instead of duplicating it in each of the buttons.
5. I removed the `top` and `position` from the buttons, as they are unnecessary in the example shown using flex, but you should adjust the exact positioning of the buttons as you like by using `padding` and/or `margin`.

Comment: The thing is that between .mainBody and buttons I have some other elements which I want also to be stable. How can I do this when expanding and when not expanding? I edited my code up